# NoReverseMatch on my form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I keep getting this `NoReverseMatch` error.
My error is at the `<form action>` tag. But if I change the format to something like the one in `<a href>` tag then everything is okay. Please guide me as I am new to Django.

```
<html>
<head><title>Feedbacks</title></head>

<body>
    {% if store_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for store in store_list %}
                <li><a href="/feedbacks/{{ store.store_name }}/add/">{{ store.store_name }}</a></li>
                <form action="{% url 'view' store.store_name %}" method="post">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" text="Add" />
                </form>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>List is empty.</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from feedback import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #/feedbacks
    url(r'^$', views.feedbacks, name="feedbacks"),
    # /feedbacks/Kenny Rogers/add/
    url(r'^(?P<store_name>.+)/add/$', views.add, name="add"),

    url(r'^(?P<store_name>.+)/view/$', views.view, name="view"),
)
```

My views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from feedback.models import Store
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.shortcuts import render

def feedbacks(request):
    store_list = Store.objects.all()
    context = {"store_list" : store_list}
    return render(request, "feedback/feedbacks.html", context)

def add(request, store_name):
    return HttpResponse("I'm at the add page of %s. " % store_name)

def view(request, store_name):
    return HttpResponse("I'm at the view page of %s. " % store_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotation marks have been allowed from django 1.5. If you are using version below it try by removing it.

```
<form action="{% url add store.store_name %}" method="post">
```

Also, you are missing the csrf token though the error is not related to that.

Comment: So, I just removed the single quote from my view and it worked. In https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/ they included a single quote.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have no `{% load url %}` or `{% load url from future %}`.
2. Raunak Agarwal correctly highlighted that you try to use 'view' function instead of 'add'. But in both cases you have the same parameter passed so it will work.

[In Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url) you can find about it.